# Difference in coefficients Polynomial regression between R,Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-regression

I currently working on a project where I have to translate [r](/questions/tagged/r) code to [python](/questions/tagged/python).

I came across an issue in Polynomial [regression](/questions/tagged/regression). There's a difference between the coefficients I got from R and Python.

**Here's my Data :**

```
stress_immo['stress immo'] = [0.0 , -0.2 ,-0.4]
stress_immo['Choc A - EQ T1'] = [-0.021951,-0.021951,-0.021951]
```

**The code given to me in R is the following :**

```
Reg_GF_S_cEQT1_A_a_RE <- lm(Choc.A...EQ.T1~stress.immo+ I(stress.immo^2), data=stress_immo)
```

The result of this is :

```
(Intercept)      -2.195e-02         NA      NA       NA
stress.immo      -9.014e-17         NA      NA       NA
I(stress.immo^2) -1.502e-16         NA      NA       NA
```

Here's my code in Python (very likely to be wrong) :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

x = (stress_immo['stress immo'].values).reshape(-1,1)
qfit = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
xq = qfit.fit_transform(x)

y = (stress_immo['Choc A - EQ T1'].values).reshape(-1,1)

qr = LinearRegression()
model = qr.fit(xq,y)
```

and here are my results :

```
print(model.coef_)
[[0. 0. 0.]]
print(model.intercept_)
[-0.02195108]
```

As you can see the intercept is correct by coefficients are always 0 (no matter what data I choose), I also tried doing a [linear-regression](/questions/tagged/linear-regression) like so:

```
x =stress_immo['stress immo'].values
x2 = np.power(stress_immo['stress immo'].values,2)
vector_row = np.array([x,x2]).reshape(-1, 2)
y = stress_immo['Choc A - EQ T1'].values
model = LinearRegression().fit(vector_row,y)
```

but the result is always the same, 0 coefficient

I would be grateful if someone could help. Thanks,

Comment: This is a fit that makes no sense at all... your response has only 1 value and of course you need an intercept only model. The coefficients present in R, they are way too small. So there's nothing wrong with the regression in R and python.

Comment: @StupidWolf so there's no issue with my code ?

Comment: It looks ok. you can also consider using statsmodels if you wanna have it similar to R. and also there is a polynomial transformation in python https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html

Comment: but if it is just x^2, that's fine